# Por que o find_packages() não encontra um dos pacotes do meu código?

Tags: python-3.x, setup

Estou tentando gerar um pacote de distribuição para o Pypi pelo `setuptools`. O problema é que a função `find_packages` não encontra uma das minhas pastas do pacote, chamada `win32`.

A árvore de diretórios é a seguinte:

```
PyMemoryEditor/
    process/
    win32/ 
    __init__.py
setup.py
```

O retorno da função é sempre esse:

```
['PyMemoryEditor', 'PyMemoryEditor.process']
```

Eu já tentei renomear a pasta para diversos nomes (win32tools, test, minhapasta, etc), mas ainda sem sucesso. O que está acontecendo? Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Abaixo está o código completo do `setup.py`:

```
from PyMemoryEditor import __version__
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("README.md") as file:
    README = file.read()

setup(
    name = "PyMemoryEditor",
    version = __version__,
    description = "Process memory reader and writer.",
    long_description = README,
    long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
    author = "My Name",
    url = "https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/PyMemoryEditor",
    license = "MIT",
    keywords = "memory writer reader",
    packages = find_packages(exclude = ("tests", "docs")),
    install_requires = ["pywin32", "psutil"]
)
```